# context sensitive resource strings as tooltips

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I suspect that the reason I haven't been able to find the answer to my question during the last couple of weeks of on/off searching is that I'm probably not using the right terms in my searches. Any pointers on what terms to use in searching or outright answers will be appreciated.

Here is the situation. I writing a `WPF/C#` application that manages data in a SQL Server database. I've templated the tool tips of buttons so they display the info I want them to show. Here is an example:

```
<Button.ToolTip>
  <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}"
           c:ToolTip.HeaderText="{x:Static p:Resources.AddRecordToolTip}"
           c:ToolTip.DescriptionText="{x:Static p:Resources.AddRecordDescription}" />
</Button.ToolTip>
```

Each tool tip has two bits of information in it.
1. The `"HeaderText"` which is a very brief description of what the button does. I.E. Add New Vendor.
2. The `"DescriptionText"` which has more detailed info about the operation of this button.

What I'd like to do is this:
The "AddRecordToolTip" resource should be something like `"Add New {0}"` so that the same resource can be used for the "HeaderText" of the "Add" buttons on each window.

The `"{0}"` should be replaced by `"Vendor"` in the `"Vendor Window",` `"Customer"` in the `"Customer Window"` etc.

Somehow I'm just not managing to find examples on how to do this. I sure there is some simple thing I'm missing or some term I'm not googleing that would give me what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your view model has a property Description, which will be "Vendor" for the Vendor Window etc...

```
<Button.ToolTip> 
  <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}" 
           c:ToolTip.HeaderText="{Binding Description, StringFormat={x:Static p:Resources.AddRecordToolTip}}" 
           c:ToolTip.DescriptionText="{x:Static p:Resources.AddRecordDescription}" /> 
</Button.ToolTip>
```